# JQUERY rotating img

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

i have an issue

i use this code to rotate my image

```
<script>
                $(document).ready(
                function(){
                    $('.music').click(function() {
                        $(this).parent().find('.musicInfo').toggle();
                        $('.arrow-img').toggleClass('rotate');
                        $('.arrow-img').toggleClass('rotate2');
                    });
                });
        </script>
```

it works but it turns all images down but i want it only to rotate the image of the div selected
this is my div/img section

```
<div id="menu-right" class="block">
                        <h1>MEER INFORMATIE</h1>
                            <?php
                                include 'voordelen.php';
                                    foreach ($result as $title) { ?>
                                        <div class='wrapper'>
                                            <div class='music'>
                                                <img id="afb"class="arrow-img rotate2" src="pictures\arrow.png"/>
                                                    <?php
                                                        echo $title['Onderwerp']
                                                    ?>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class='musicInfo'>
                                               <?php
                                                 echo $title['Omschrijving']
                                               ?>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                            <?php } ?>
                </div>
```

look this is normal whitout an click

As you can see they all turn at once

Comment: can you have a demo/fiddle of your problem.

Comment: Rendered HTML only please. This is not a PHP question, we don't need to read PHP code.

Comment: ![whitout an click][1]
  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/23Ty1.png
this is when i click
  ![clicked version][2]



  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/21Oet.jpg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify the image you want to rotate

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.music').click(function () {
        $(this).parent().find('.musicInfo').toggle();
        $(this).find('.arrow-img').toggleClass('rotate');
        $(this).find('.arrow-img').toggleClass('rotate2');
    });
});
```

Comment: i was going to but i had to wait 5 min

Answer (score 0):

Or use this for better performance

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div.music').click(function () {
        $(this).parent().find('div.musicInfo').toggle();
        $(this).find('img.arrow-img').toggleClass('rotate');
        $(this).find('img.arrow-img').toggleClass('rotate2');
    });
});
```